# Как добавить водяной знак на страницу с непрозрачным изображением?

Tags: java, .net, pdf, sdk, itext

Можно ли добавить прозрачный водяной знак поверх изображения? Сейчас я использую следующий код:

```js
PdfContentByte canvas = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(
    canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, watermark, 298, 421, 45);
```

Он работает неплохо, но если в содержимом есть изображение, то оно скрывает водяной знак.

Answer (score 0):

Если все формы в вашем PDF-файле (изображения, а также цветные формы) непрозрачные, то вам нужно добавлять водяной знак поверх содержимого:

```js
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage().newContentStreamAfter(), new PdfResources(), pdfDoc);
```

Так текст будет расположен поверх изображений. Однако он может скрывать важную информацию. Для того чтобы этого избежать, нужно создать прозрачность.
Есть простой пример по созданию прозрачности. Он называется [TransparentWatermark](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/samples/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/stamper/TransparentWatermark.java). Посмотрим на результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Три разных водяных знака

Сначала я добавляю текст «This watermark is added UNDER the existing content» под существующее содержимое. Часть текста скрыта (как указано в вашем вопросе). Затем я добавляю текст «This watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content» поверх существующего содержимого. Этого может быть достаточно, если у вас нет важной информации, которая может быть скрыта. Текст «This TRANSPARENT watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content» добавлен следующим образом:

```js
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
    PdfCanvas under = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage().newContentStreamBefore(), new PdfResources(), pdfDoc);
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA));
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This watermark is added UNDER the existing content")
            .setFont(font).setFontSize(15);
    new Canvas(under, pdfDoc, pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize())
            .showTextAligned(p, 297, 550, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    PdfCanvas over = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage());
    over.setFillColor(Color.BLACK);
    p = new Paragraph("This watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
            .setFont(font).setFontSize(15);
    new Canvas(over, pdfDoc, pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize())
            .showTextAligned(p, 297, 500, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    p = new Paragraph("This TRANSPARENT watermark is added ON TOP OF the existing content")
            .setFont(font).setFontSize(15);
    over.saveState();
    PdfExtGState gs1 = new PdfExtGState();
    gs1.setFillOpacity(0.5f);
    over.setExtGState(gs1);
    new Canvas(over, pdfDoc, pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize())
            .showTextAligned(p, 297, 450, 1, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
    over.restoreState();
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Дополнительные советы и рекомендации:

- Всегда используйте `saveState()` и `restoreState()` во время изменения графического состояния. Если этого не делать, могут появиться нежелательные эффекты, например, изменения повлияют на другое содержимое (например, все содержимое может стать прозрачным).
- Параметры рендеринга текста по умолчанию имеют значение «fill», поэтому я изменяю прозрачность заливки.
- В этом случае я меняю значение прозрачности заливки на 50 % (0.5f). Прозрачность текста регулируется с помощью изменения значения от 0.0f до 1.0f.